# Sets re: equality and subsets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

*The italics are my comments.*

*This is a proof from a text on abstract algebra that seems a bit ambiguous. But I'm just learning sans instructor.
My question is: is there a convention in set theory proofs that I'm missing?*

Theorem 1.2 (De Morgan’s Laws) Let A and B be sets. Then

1. (A ∪ B)' = A' ∩ B'
2. (A ∩ B)' = A' ∪ B'

Proof.

Part 1,  show that (A ∪ B)' ⊂ A' ∩ B'

and

Part 2,  that (A ∪ B)' ⊃ A' ∩ B'

*I understand that if A ⊂ B and A ⊃ B then A=B and so the two conditions above make sense.*

To show part 1,

Let x ∈ (A ∪ B)'

Then x $\notin$ A ∪ B. So x is neither in A nor in B, by the
definition of the union of sets. By the definition of the complement, x ∈ A'
and x ∈ B'.  Therefore, x ∈ A' ∩ B' and we have (A ∪ B)' ⊂ A' ∩ B'

*I understand that he is just showing that the right hand side of the required expression can be deduced.  But he uses the left side to deduce it.  I.e., it seems to me that rather than say
"and we have (A ∪ B)' ⊂ A' ∩ B' " 
it it seems to me that it should be: 
"and we have (A ∪ B)' = A' ∩ B' ".  The reason I say this is because x ∈ (A ∪ B)' AND x ∈ A' ∩ B'
And he repeats the process for the left hand side.*

To show part 2, 
show the reverse inclusion. Suppose that x ∈ A' ∩ B'.  Then x ∈ A'
and x ∈ B', and so x $\notin$ A and x $\notin$ B. Thus x $\notin$ A ∪ B and so x ∈ (A ∪ B)' .  Hence, (A ∪ B)' ⊃ A' ∩ B' and so (A ∪ B)' = A' ∩ B'

End of proof

*Again, he is deducing one side from the other and it seems he should conclude they are equal rather than say the left hand side is the superset of the right hand side.
Should I worry about this or am I making it more difficult that it really is?*

Comment: We  show $\forall x \,(x\in P\implies x\in Q)$ and then we show $\forall x\,(x\in Q \implies x\in P)$ and conclude $P=Q$. It's not subtle.

Comment: "it it seems to me that it should be: "and we have (A ∪ B)' = A' ∩ B' ". The reason I say this is because x ∈ (A ∪ B)' AND x ∈ A' ∩ B' "  That's true for *this* $x$ that was in $(A\cup B)'$.  It might not be true for some $y \in A'\cap B'$ but $y \not \in (A \cup B)'$.  He has proven *every* $x \in (A\cup B)'$ is also in $A'\cap B'$ but he has *not* proven (yet) that ever $y \in A'\cap B'$ is also in $(A\cup B)'$.

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful :)  So I'm seeing this as something like "Think of the left and right hand sides as black boxes  even though there is an explicit relationship that times them together, you still have to satisfy the subset/superset identity to complete the proof."

Answer (score 1):

One of the basic definitions of set theory is that the inclusion statement $X \subset Y$ is equivalent to the statement "if $x \in X$ then $x \in Y$". That is exactly what is being proved in part 1: if $x \in (A \cup B)'$ then $x \in A' \cap B'$. And like all "if-then" proofs, the way that the proof goes is that you *assume* $x \in (A \cup B)'$, and using that assumption you *prove* $x \in A' \cap B'$. Similarly for part 2.

Answer (score 0):

To prove that $A = B$ it's not enough to prove $x\in A \implies x \in B$ becuase theres always a possibility that there is some $y \in B$ but $y \not \in A$.

You must prove  $x \in A \implies x\in B$ and *ALSO* one of the two following:

i) $x \in B \implies x\in A$ or

ii) $x \not \in A \implies x\not \in B$

either one will do but you can't ignore them.  Otherwise you can have a $y \in B$ but $y \not \in A$.

You simply can't prove *anything* about the $y$s *not* in $A$ by only looking at the $y$s that *are* in $A$.

....

In first half of the proof he only did $x \in (A\cup B)' \implies x \in A'\cap B'$.  He did *nothing* to show that there was not any $y \in A'\cap B'$ where $y \not \in (A\cup B)'$.

That's why he had to do the second half of the proof.

=====

As a counter example consider this "proof" that $\mathbb Z = \mathbb Q$.

Let $x \in \mathbb Z$.  Then $x = \frac x1$; $x, 1\in \mathbb Z$ so $x=\frac x1 \in \mathbb Q$.  So $x \in \mathbb Q$.  As $x \in \mathbb Z$ and $x \in \mathbb Q$ that means $\mathbb Z = \mathbb Q$.

Do you see what is wrong?  We *never* considered anything that *wasn't* in $\mathbb Z$!

Comment: Another way of putting it.  when we say $x \in A$ we are saying $x$ may be *any* element of $A$.  When we prove that $x \in B$ we are not saying that $x$ can be any element of $B$, we are saying that $x$ is only an element of $B$ that is also in $A$, there can be other elements in $B$ that are not in $A$.